# How to separate text with PHP

Tags: php

Well I am trying to make a simple php system.
Anywise I need to separate the text when I want to add it to the database.
So for example I want to add:

```
abc:123
```

I want that the : will be the separater, so it'll look like this:

```
abc 
123
```

And then both will go to a different table.

Could someone help me with this? As I am not an experience PHP coder, yet I am willing to learn how to do this.

Kind regards

Comment: If you literally copy paste your title into google, the first result is [explode](http://be2.php.net/explode)

Comment: `$data = explode(":", $yourString);`

Comment: @meda, it'd be `$data = explode(":", $yourString);` actually.

Comment: I would suggest you to learn the basics, grab a PHP book for beginners and start reading.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty basic stuff..

```
$data = explode(':','abc:123');

foreach($data as $word)
{
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Split:

```
<?php
$data = "abc:123";
list ($var1, $var2) = split (':', $data);
echo "Var1: $var1; Var2: $var2;<br />\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
abc:123
```

Is a string. Let's define it as a variable:

```
$origin = "abc:123";
```

You can split the string, using `:` as the separator.

```
$separator = ":";
$exploded = explode($separator, $origin);
```

Now you have an array which you can use to access `abc` and `123` individually.

```
$pre = $exploded[0];
$post = $exploded[1];
```

**You don't know how many splits there will be?**

That's okay. Your array simply increases, meaning you can simply loop through the array and handle the values.

```
foreach ($exploded as $split)
{
    // Do something with $split
}
```

Comment: So for example if I use a textarea, and let the $string use the textarea (sorry don't know how to call it) it'll do the same for the whole list which will be put in the textarea?

Comment: Your `$exploded` array simply becomes larger, you can use a loop to parse every instance of the array until it's finished.

Comment: So, yes. More or less it's the same.